# Where Windows 10 stores its disabled startup program list?

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-8, windows-10, regedit

As I know Windows 10 doesn't have ms-config we can enable or disable a startup application with task manager so if I disable a program then where it stores its information?  In Windows 7 we can get the information from

```
RegistryKey HKLM2 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\MSConfig\\startupreg", true);
foreach (string programs in HKLM2.GetSubKeyNames())
{
    MessageBox.Show(programs);
}
```

When we disabled an application it delete the key I mean the key under run or run  and stores it here so what is the same thing in Windows 10 or Windows 8?

Comment: [Disable startup program in Window 10](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/disable-startup-programs-windows-10/). For compatibility Window 10 should use same registry entries. What doesn't work?

Comment: SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Shared Tools\\MSConfig\\startupreg doesnot exists in win10

Comment: Check out `HKEY_USERS\[CurrentUserId]\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StartupApproved\Run`, it seems what disabling/enabling startup items changes values there.

Comment: is there any way to get current user id?? and many thanks for the answer

Comment: use RegFromApp (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/reg_file_from_application.html), select Taskmgr, do the changes and RegFromApp should show you which setting gets modified.

Comment: thnx everyone thnx for the help

Comment: ok, wre you able to find the location? Where is is stored?

Comment: its stored on HKEY_USERS\[CurrentUserId]\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\S‌​tartupApproved\Run]

Comment: Anyone know the difference between run and run32?